# Mishkan before/after Egel (Rashi & Ramban)

Tags: time, rashi, mishkan-tabernacle, golden-calf-egel, ramban

The Ramban and Rashi disagree when the Mishkan was commanded to be built. Either before or after the Egel HaZahav respectively. Can you provide SOURCES that are able to reconcile their differences?

Ramban: Shemos 25:2 - (My understanding) The Mikshkan was the first commandment to the Jewish people after Har Sinai.

Ramban orders the process as follows

(A)Har Sinahi Parshas Yisro/Mishpatim 19-24
(B)Commandment to Build Mishkan Teruman/Tetzaveh/Ki-Sisa 25-31
(C)Chet Ha'Egel Ki Sisa 32-34
(D) Building of the Mishkan Vayakhel/Pekudei 35-40

Rashi: Shemos 31:18 - (Translation) Not before but after. The making of the Egel was before the commandment to build the mishkan

Rashi switches B & C

Comment: You could improve this question by including citations of Ramban's and Rashi's opinions and by including more detail about their respective positions. Also, by "reconcile" in the last sentence, do you mean "choose which one is right," or somehow "figure out a way they can both be right"? Please clarify.

Comment: Reconcile means to cause two (seemingly) opposite forces to coexist.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I was wondering if that's what you really meant because it seems like a tall order in this case.

Answer (score 2):

See [this article](http://www.chabad.org/global/popup/default_cdo/aid/1329/jewish/Sin-and-Sanctity.htm), which brings 3 opinions about the timeline (Ramban, Rashi, and Zohar).

The article (based on a Sicha from the Lubavitcher Rebbe) explains that the three opinions are discussing whether the commandment to make a dwelling place for G-d apply only to a Tzaddik, also a Baal Teshuva, or even a Rasha.

The Rebbe then says that "These and these are the words of The Living G-d" and explains how all the opinions are correct.

Answer (score 1):

at the 7:30 mark in the audio of the following link.  http://www.simpletoremember.com/media/a/mishkan-n-human-individuality/

Comment: Welcome to Judaism.SE, and thanks very much for the answer! Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Note that [editing in](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/15648/edit) a summary of the audio shiur to your answer will greatly improve its value to the community.